# Place text from inputbox in a string

Tags: autohotkey

I'm looking for a ahk script to do the following:

1. Show popup box
2. Enter text
3. Show standardtext + string in popup box.

So that when for example I press #r i get a popup box, i type in Marc and I get

"dear regards Marc".

So in Java it would be be something like

```
var1 = inputBox("whats your name")
var NameRegards = function(text){
"dear regards" + var1
}
show NameRegards
```

Anybody a clue how I can manage this in ahk?

Comment: The code you posted isn't Java. If anything, it looks like JavaScript.  Where exactly do you have problems implementing it in AHK?

Comment: I mean Javascript indeed. Anyway suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: On how to fix what? The JavaScript? I don't see anything else to fix here...

Comment: I mean how I can achieve this in autohotkey...

Comment: Have you tried to achieve it? If so, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

How about doing it exactly as you described?

```
InputBox, varName, Name input, What's your name?
MsgBox , , Output, Dear regards %varName%
```

Works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an untested start..

```
#SingleInstance Force
#Persistent

Return ; Stop the startup lines otherwise #r will run on startup...

#r:: ; [Win]+r to start this script
InputBox, MyName, This is your Windows Title, Type your name:
SendInput, Dear regards`, %MyName% ; Using `(On ~ key on US KB) to literally  print a comma
; SendInput, % "Dear regards, " MyName ; Alternative way
Return
```